# Check login and password from array with users accounts info

Tags: php, arrays, authentication

My array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [login] => kayover
            [password] => test
            [email] => mail@gmail.com
            [date_reg] => 18:18, 10 апреля 2017
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [login] => user_2
            [password] => password_2
            [email] => mail_2@gmail.com
            [date_reg] => 18:18, 10 апреля 2017
        )

)
```

I can get this info like this:

```
foreach($users_arr as $user) {
    echo $user['login'];
    echo $user['password'];
    echo $user['email'];
    echo $user['date_reg'];
}
```

But how I can check if given login and password in my form is match one of this, inserted in main array, arrays?

---

Edited: Added html form code.

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="/login">
    <table width="380" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="8"><tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">логин:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="login" value="" style="width: 120px" maxlength="64"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">пароль:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" style="width: 120px" maxlength="64"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="войти" class="button"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</form>
```

Comment: why would you want to use plain text passwords to start with? is this db-related or from a text file? and what is it for?

Comment: @Fred-ii- This array was generated from text file with improvised database.

Comment: *"But how I can check if given login and password in my form"* - Hard to say since you didn't include the (html)/form and the rest of the php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wait please. | Added.

Comment: @chris85 Will try this now, thanks.

Comment: @chris85 Looks like it works like it should, thank you again. Don't know why I doesn't get it without asking question here :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a conditional (`if`) inside your `foreach` loop and the authentication should work.

```
foreach($users_arr as $user) {
    if($user['password'] == $_POST['password'] && $user['email'] == $_POST['email'])
         echo 'You are a valid user.';
         break; //You know the user 
    }
}
```